# Mongo Index not being used

Tags: mongodb

I created an index around several items for a particular query I am doing:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "MODIFIED" : -1,
        "state" : 1,
        "fail" : 1,
        "generated" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "foo.bar",
    "name" : "MODIFIED_-1_state_1_fail_1_generated"
}
```

However when I execute my query, it doesn't apear to be using my index.  Could you please provide some insite into what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
db.foo.find(    {
    "$or": [
        {
            "MODIFIED": {
                "$gt": {
                    "sec": 1321419600,
                    "usec": 0
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$or": [
                {"state": "ca"},
                {"state": "ok"}
            ]
        }
    ],
    "$and": [
        {"fail": {"$ne": 1}},
        {"generated": {"$exists": false}}
    ]
}).explain();
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "nscanned" : 464215,
    "nscannedObjects" : 464215,
    "n" : 0,
    "millis" : 7549,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a good reason your index cannot be used for your query and I also think there are some issues with the query itself. The reason it's not hitting an index is because of the nested $or operator by the way but I think your actual problem is a lack of understanding on all the operators available to you in MongoDB :

First of all, your nested $or to check if the state is either "ca" or "ok" is not necessary and ( since it's the main reason you're not hitting your index) can be replaced with `state:{$in:["ca", "ok"]}` which does the exact same thing. Now your query is :

```
db.foo.find(    {
    "$or": [
        {
            "MODIFIED": {
                "$gt": {
                    "sec": 1321419600,
                    "usec": 0
                }
            }
        },
        {
            state:{$in:["ca", "ok"]}            
        }
    ],
    "$and": [
        {"fail": {"$ne": 1}},
        {"generated": {"$exists": false}}
    ]
}).explain();
```

And it will hit your index. Your second issue is that a top-level $and clause is not necessary. Note that `AND(OR(A, B), AND(C, D)) = AND(OR(A, B), C, D)`. This query does the same :

```
db.foo.find(    {
    "$or": [
        {
            "MODIFIED": {
                "$gt": {
                    "sec": 1321419600,
                    "usec": 0
                }
            }
        },
        {
            state:{$in:["ca", "ok"]}            
        }
    ],

    "fail": {"$ne": 1},
    "generated": {"$exists": false}

}).explain();
```

Which still hits the index :

```
{
        "clauses" : [
                {
                        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor MODIFIED_-1_state_1_fail_1_generated_1 multi",
                        "nscanned" : 0,
                        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                        "n" : 0,
                        "millis" : 1,
                        "nYields" : 0,
                        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "indexOnly" : false,
                        "indexBounds" : {
                                "MODIFIED" : [
                                        [
                                                {
                                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "sec" : 1321419600,
                                                        "usec" : 0
                                                }
                                        ]
                                ],
                                "state" : [
                                        [
                                                {
                                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                                }
                                        ]
                                ],
                                "fail" : [
                                        [
                                                {
                                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                                },
                                                1
                                        ],
                                        [
                                                1,
                                                {
                                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                                }
                                        ]
                                ],
                                "generated" : [
                                        [
                                                null,
                                                null
                                        ]
                                ]
                        }
                },
                {
                        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                        "nscanned" : 0,
                        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                        "n" : 0,
                        "millis" : 1,
                        "nYields" : 0,
                        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "indexOnly" : false,
                        "indexBounds" : {

                        }
                }
        ],
        "nscanned" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
        "n" : 0,
        "millis" : 1
}
```

Hope that helps! By the way it's slightly more conventional to start the first key in your compound index with order 1 and the second with -1. Note that the -1 is only used to determine the direction relative to the previous field.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer; along with a bit of education!

Comment: adjusted and everything is working excellent; much faster. Thank you again for your help!