# Mongo explicit/implicit AND behaving differently

Tags: c#, mongodb, indexing, mongodb-indexes

**Basic question:**

Are the following 2 queries meant to be equivalent?

```
(A) coll.find(k1:v1, k2:v2)             // List of fields
(B) coll.find($and: [{k1:v1}, {k2:v2}]) // $and the list of fields
```

If so, why do they show different behaviour? (see below). If not, how can I generate the former in C#?

**Further discussion**

I am indexing fields in a subdocument. Query (A) uses the indexes correctly but Query (B) does not.

Here is some sample code (it will work directly in the mongo console):

```
{
  _id : Guid
  ..other stuff..
  Fields: { K1: V1, K2: V2 ...}
}

// Populate
db.test.insert({_id:1,Fields:{K1:123,K2:456}})
db.test.insert({_id:2,Fields:{K1:456,K2:123}})

// Index on fields of subdocument
db.test.ensureIndex({"Fields.K1": 1})
db.test.ensureIndex({"Fields.K2": 1})...

// Execute some queries
db.test.find({_id: {$lt: 20}, "$or": [{"Fields.K1": 123}, {"Fields.K2": 123}]}).explain()
db.test.find({$and: [{_id: {$lt: 20}}, {"$or": [{"Fields.K1": 123}, {"Fields.K2": 123}]}]}).explain()
```

The first query uses the indexes as expected. The second does not.

**Summary of questions**

1. Are the two find() queries equivalent?
2. If so, why is their behaviour different? If not, how are they different?
3. How can I generate the find() without $and using the C# driver?

**Edit**--------

For the record, the syntax I am using in C# is something along the lines of:

```
coll.find(Query.And([<id query>, <fields query>]));
```

Generating a QueryDocument manually does not work as it cannot contain multiple $or queries as $or is used as the key of a dictionary (and I need multiple $or in my actual query).

Comment: From the documentation: `MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma separated list of expressions` Also check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280540/mongo-index-not-being-used

Comment: If that is the case, why is the behaviour of an explicit AND different from an implicit AND? The question about generating a query without an explicit AND in C# driver still stands. I am currently doing coll.find(Query.And([<the id query>, <the Fields query>])).

Answer (score 0):

I have determined that the mongo documentation is somewhat misleading when it states that it provides an implicit AND when specifying a comma separated list of operations. Take the following query:

```
// Returns 19 documents on sample data.
coll.find({{a simple query}, {an $or query}, {another $or query}})
```

In the above case, I find that one of the $or queries may be ignored. That is, the 3 queries are not being combined with an $and. Providing an explicit $and fixes this:

```
// Returns 2 documents on the same sample data.
coll.find({$and: [{a simple query}, {an $or query}, {another $or query}]})
```

Comment: This isn't correct.  For an implicit AND query you don't pass multiple objects to `coll.find`, you pass one object with multiple fields that represent the multiple terms that are ANDed together.

Comment: Thanks, edited. I didn't mean for it to appear as a list of separate queries. It is a single query with subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the two queries are functionally equivalent.

Regarding performing this query

```js
db.test.find({
    _id: {$lt: 20}, 
    "$or": [{"Fields.K1": 123}, {"Fields.K2": 123}]
})
```

using the C# driver, you can do that using:

```
var query = Query.And(Query.LT("_id", 20), 
                      Query.Or(Query.EQ("Fields.K1", 123), 
                               Query.EQ("Fields.K2", 123)));
var docs = test.Find(query);
```

Even though `Query.And` is used, an implicit AND query is generated as you can see if you inspect the output of calling `query.ToJson()`:

```js
{ "_id" : { "$lt" : 20 }, "$or" : [{ "Fields.K1" : 123 }, { "Fields.K2" : 123 }] }
```

which matches the original query.

As for why some explicit `$and` queries don't use an index (or uses a different index as in this case) where the equivalent implicit AND query does, it would appear that Mongo's internal ability to convert an explicit AND to an implicit one is imperfect and that's why you only want to use `$and` if you have to.

Comment: I ran some tests in C# and agree with you on this point. I was thrown off as C# driver seems to generate an explicit $and in some cases and not others, and I missed the latter cases. However, can you explain then why the behaviour of .explain() on the two queries in the original question differs? Then this answer will be correct.

Comment: @mmmdreg See updated answer.  In short, only use `$and` if you have to so that you don't rely on Mongo to figure out whether whether it can be converted into an implicit AND.

Comment: Thanks. It appears the inconsistent behaviour has been rectified as of mongo 2.5.3 due to their recent query framework enhancements. See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11517